# jquery get last li of each nested list

Tags: jquery

if I have a nested list like this:

```
<ul id="test">
  <li>
    <ul>
       <li>blah1</li>
       <li>blah2</li>
       <li>blah3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <ul>
       <li>blah6</li>
       <li>blah7</li>
       <li>blah8</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using jquery How do I select the last element of each nested ul (i.e. the blah3 and blah8)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/NxZpN/

```
$('#test ul li:last-child');
```

Comment: if i have images at blah 3 and blah8 called "down.gif". how can i hide it with jquery. I tried $('#test ul li:last-child img[src*="down.gif"]').hide(); but it does not work

Comment: You code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/FjXg9/ You must have some other issue. Is `gif` uppercase or something?

Comment: not sure why but does not work. please see http://jsfiddle.net/rayse/LWWSk/ for volume 1 i click a few chapters and the last li does not show "down" after I click "add volume" and then add a chapter for volume 2, strange enough it adds a "down" on volume 1. it is supposed to never show the last "down" on either volume 1 or volume 2

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) as [in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) :

```
$('#test ul li:last-child')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('li ul li:last-child').css('color', 'orange');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jSWkP/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#test ul li:last-child')
```